# Preparing a String to be used in Json

Tags: c#, json, string

I have a string where I need to use as the body of a JSON object. I know its possible that the data could have quotes in it, so I parse through to add an escape character to those instance of quotes.. like so:

```
string NewComment = comment.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

However, somehow on some edgecases, a quote still makes it through. I don't know if this is something with UTF or some other issue, But I am trying to find a function that would safely create a json compatible string, I figured there has to be something like this out there, or a regex way of doing so.

Basically a TLDR is how to create a json syntax safe string from a c# string

Comment: The real problem is likely how you are creating the JSON.

Comment: Use a serializer, like JSON.Net for example. Don't waste your time trying to handcraft JSON.

Comment: This feels like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that could be solved by using a proper library for building and parsing json.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is don't do it this way. What if you have escaped quotes in your string? `"Hello \"World\""` would become invalid with such a simple approach: `"Hello \\"World\\""`. JSON.Net or Newtonsoft are going to save you so many headaches in the long run.